# Parabolic river-bed: wetted perimeter as a function of area filled with water

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections, area

Suppose we have a parabola-shaped cross-section of a riverbed, filled with water to a height y = h in the vertical direction, with the surface of the water extending between x = a and x = b in the horizontal direction. How could one express the perimeter of the riverbed wetted by water as a function of the area of water A contained in the cross-section, which is a function of time.

I imagine a good starting point is to apply the integral expression for the arc-length of a parabolic function $\int_a^{b} dx\sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2}$, with $f(x) = cx^{2}$ as the input function, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not exactly clear from your problem what are the known quantities. Is it only area? Or is it area and the depth of the water? Or is it the depth of the water and the extent in the $x$ direction?

Comment: @Andrei please see my edits

Comment: The area of the cross section is given by ${2\over3}(b-a)h$. And $$c={4h\over(b-a)^2}.$$ But the integral should span the interval $[-(b-a)/2,(b-a)/2]$.